# Rails 3: A/B Testing App Features

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best way of AB Testing new features and keeping track of the results?

Regards,
Donald

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem called [Vanity](https://github.com/assaf/vanity) which is designed for A/B testing in Rails (and appears to work in Rails 3).

Here's a [tutorial on Vanity](http://webandy.com/articles/a-b-testing-with-vanity).

Answer (score 0):

I've just released a gem that integrates the Google Analytics Experiments API with Rails.  It is pretty full-featured and the reporting is right in Google Analytics.  It uses a bandit algorithm, allows you to specify a subset of the audience to test and more.

https://github.com/dlangevin/gxapi_rails

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used [split](https://github.com/andrew/split) and I've found it to be quite nice, especially with respect to the dashboard it provides for you.